# How to fit tabWidget size and main window size with each other, when changing size of main window in QT (C++)?

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt5

I need to fit tabWidgets size with main window size in QT5. Here is the code in C++:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDesktopWidget>
#include <QSize>


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    float screenAspectRatio = 0.8;
    resize(QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry(this).size() * screenAspectRatio); // Resize windows size
    ui->tabWidget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Preferred);
    ui->tabWidget->resize(QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry(this).size() * screenAspectRatio);//Resize Tab size
    //ui->tabWidget->setWindowModality(center)
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

When `screenAspectRatio` parameter is changed, it crops or adds empty spaces to tabWidget as below images.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I need the tabWidget to be fit in main window. Any help is appreciated.